# Why am I getting Run-time error 429 in Excel VB?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm getting the Run-time error. Activex Component Can't create object.

I have tried everything from re-installing office to check in my registry with no luck. I checked my admin priveldges and that didn't fix it. My code is correct

Here's code:

```
Sub GetSheetInfo()


Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbXL = CreateObject("D:\project\Ruby\Live info Ruby.xls")


    Range("A9:H800").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    Windows("Live info Ruby.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Ruby - 2020").Select
    Range("A155:g950").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Project Duration.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Frequency").Select
    Range("A9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
       , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False

    wbXL.Close

End Sub
```

**Basically all this is suppose to do is copy from another excel file sheet and paste it into another excel file (the one with the Macro)**

I'll take any and all suggestions including code changes

Comment: Note that VBA and VB.NET are not the same thing.

Comment: Verify that "D:\project\Ruby\Live info Ruby.xls" exists and that you have access rights to it.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I did and I do

Comment: Instead of CreateObject, just open the workbook. `Set wbXL = Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\project\Ruby\Live info Ruby.xls")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using the ".Select" method when copying and pasting. I would start adopting this method instead:

Dim and copy the desired range instead.

```
Sub GetSheetInfo()

Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
Dim CWB As Workbook
    Set CWB = Thisworkbook
    Set wbXL = Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\project\Ruby\Live info Ruby.xls")

Range("A9:H800").ClearContents

Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set CopyRange = wbXL.Sheets("Ruby - 2020").Range("A155:G950")
    CopyRange.Copy
        CWB.Sheets("Frequency").Range("A9").PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Added "False" to not save workbook when closing. You can remove this if needed
wbXL.Close False 

End Sub
```

You can use this to see if excel is able to open the file. If it is able to open the file, it will tell you the path that it used. Make sure the path you have in the code you choose to use matches this path letter by letter.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Test()

Dim FileOpen As FileDialog
Dim fullpath As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select a File"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Show
    fullpath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

MsgBox fullpath

Workbooks.Open fullpath

End Sub
```

Comment: I left out your second paste. You can through that back in at the bottom.

Comment: no issues with code but again, error is referencing the file path but this time it's: "Office has detected a problem with this file. To help protect your computer this file cannot be opened"

Comment: Others have given good tips for finding out if there is something wrong with the the file path. If windows finder can find the file path, you can add a open file dialogue temporarily to see if excel can even open that file. Is the file in question encrypted (password)?

Comment: The file can be opened and the file path is correct. How do I manually import?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no fix for this.........I ran the new code and it showed my path as being equal to what was displayed........Thank you for your help. Very good answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetSheetInfo()


Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbXL = CreateObject("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")


    Range("A9:H800").Select
```

You need to copy and paste exactly what you have as your file path into windows explorer and see if it opens. I suggest double checking your file extension and making sure that you dont need to use

```
Set wbXL = CreateObject("D:\project\Ruby\Live info Ruby.xlsx")
```

When i try to use a file location that doesnt exist, I get your error, if the file does exist, it works just fine.

Comment: Is it possible to use the IP address of the network drive to the file location?

Comment: Well that wouldn't really make sense to me, youre just trying to access a file on your computer. If its on a network drive you could do \\servername\folder1\folder2\item.xlsx